# Type Mismatch - Array[Map[String,Array[Map[String,Long]]]]

Tags: scala

```
  val rawFacets: Array[Map[String,Array[Map[String,Long]]]] = response.getFacetFields.asScala.map(facetGroup => {
    val name = facetGroup.getName.toString
    val values = facetGroup.getValues.asScala.map(facet => {
      Map(facet.getName -> facet.getCount)
    })
    Map(name -> values)
  })
```

I am getting an error that my types don't match up:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long]]]]
 required: Array[Map[String,Array[Map[String,Long]]]]
```

I am a newbie to Scala, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: then change the return type according to the found one and you should be fine

Comment: I know i can do that, my q is, why the types I provided aren't good enough. I know that I shouldn't have to specify the full description of a type every time.

Comment: By default, a Map should refer to the immutable scala collection map. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: but mutable buffer is not equal to immutable Array

Comment: How would a produce an Array? Please explain what a buffer is. Is every mapped collection a buffer by default?

Comment: try casting . I have tried to answer below

Comment: Please, never cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the casting as following works

```
val rawFacets: Array[Map[String,Array[Map[String,Long]]]] = response.getFacetFields.asScala.map(facetGroup => {
    val name = facetGroup.getName.toString
    val values = facetGroup.getValues.asScala.map(facet => {
      Map(facet.getName -> facet.getCount)
    })
    Map(name -> values)
  }).asInstanceOf[Array[Map[String, Array[Map[String, Long]]]]]
```

or

```
val rawFacets: Array[Map[String,Array[Map[String,Long]]]] = response.getFacetFields.asScala.map(facetGroup => {
    val name = facetGroup.getName.toString
    val values = facetGroup.getValues.asScala.map(facet => {
      Map(facet.getName -> facet.getCount)
    }).toArray
    Map(name -> values)
  }).toArray
```

Comment: [ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to [Lscala.collection.immutable.Map;]

Comment: great to hear that @AvremelKaminetzky. first one is same as well and I wonder why it didn't work

Comment: They are not the same at all. The error is that Buffer and Array are two different things. The conversion method is necessary